# Change Div ID to Validate

Tags: php, html, validation, content-management-system

I am using a lightweight CMS that has the option to repeat regions. In order for the region to be repeatable, it must have an id. When the region is repeated so is the id. This causes my code to invalidate.

I was hoping there was a way to change all matching id's (example) to (example-1), (example-2), etc... so that it would validate. I was able to do this through JQuery, but it still did not validate (I am assuming because Javascript is client side), which is why I though PHP might work.

Thank you for your time,
Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't validate through the W3C validator because it just processes the HTML.

Why don't you change them, and you can't do it manually, use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (or equivalent).

1. Iterate through the elements with `id` that isn't unique.
2. Tack on a number.
3. Save back.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am still learning PHP and Javascript, so could you explain a little more. And to clarify, you are correct, I can not change them manually.